# Can an aboleth enslave three player characters in one encounter?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, combat

The entry on the aboleth (MM p.8) says about *Enslave (SU)*

> Three times per day, an aboleth can attempt to enslave **any one** living creature within 30 feet.

Does that mean it could enslave three player characters in one encounter and **any one** means just one at the time? Or does it mean it can only enslave one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an ability you can use three times per day. Each time you use it, that particular usage targets one living creature. But that targeting of one creature is specific to that particular usage—a separate usage is in no way required to target the same creature.

This is the standard way of writing daily-limited abilities in D&D 3.5e. **Everything** uses wording like this. Shared targeting restrictions are very much unusual, and would require specific and explicit verbiage explaining it in order to operate that way under the rules.